# How to find the last item from list have the same item using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class Record

```
public class Record
{
    public string recordID { get; set; }

    public string recordName { get; set; }
}
```

And a list records include many record, they may be equal

```
List<Record> records = new List<Record>();

records.Add(new Record { recordID = "1", recordName = "name1" });
records.Add(new Record { recordID = "2", recordName = "name2" });
records.Add(new Record { recordID = "3", recordName = "name3" });
records.Add(new Record { recordID = "4", recordName = "name4" });
records.Add(new Record { recordID = "1", recordName = "name1" });
records.Add(new Record { recordID = "2", recordName = "name2" });
records.Add(new Record { recordID = "3", recordName = "name3" });
```

from this list

> I wanna search the last item from list where recordID is the same

and do something

for example：find the last same items from list and then color it

```
records.All(p =>{
    (p.recordID == 3 /*any recordID*/ 
    && /*the record of the same is the last in list*/
    ? "<span style='corlor:red'>" + p.recordName + "</span>"
    : "<span style='corlor:green'>" + p.recordName + "</span>");
    return true;
});
```

thanks

Comment: Group your records and afterwwards call Last() on each group

Comment: Separate data handling and presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class SOProblem1
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var records = new List<Record>
        {
            new Record {recordID = "1", recordName = "name1"},
            new Record {recordID = "2", recordName = "name2"},
            new Record {recordID = "3", recordName = "name3"},
            new Record {recordID = "4", recordName = "name4"},
            new Record {recordID = "1", recordName = "name1"},
            new Record {recordID = "2", recordName = "name2"},
            new Record {recordID = "3", recordName = "name3"}
        };

        var t = records.GroupBy(x => x.recordID);

        foreach (var record in t)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(record.Last().recordName);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Record
{
    public string recordID { get; set; }

    public string recordName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first select all the records having the recordID you want and then use the last().  Example you need to retrieve the records for @recordID =3 , then the query should be :

```
  var lastRecord= record.where(p=> p.recordID==3).Last();
```